# Rails not returning all HABTM objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a HABTM set up for my Places and Amenities models:

```
class Place
  has_and_belongs_to_many :amenities

class Amenity
  has_and_belongs_to_many :places
  has_and_belongs_to_many :place_filters
```

I also have a Filter model that allows admins to assign which amenities to filter the Places by later on:

```
Class PlaceFilter
  has_and_belongs_to_many :amenities
```

I have this query that I use to lookup for places with filtered amenities:

```
@filter = Filter.find(params[:id])
@places = Place.includes(:amenities).where('amenities.id': @filter.amenities.pluck(:id))
```

The query works correctly, BUT when I iterate over places I get only ONE amenity to each of them (the one that I am filtering by), even if the place has 10 amenities. I don't understand, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause in the line where you select all places filters out all other amenities.

By [reloading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-and-belongs-to-many-collection-reload) the association you should get back all amenities per place:

```
@places.each do |place|
  amenities = place.amenities.reload
  # ...
end
```

This will perform a fresh read from the database (one additional query executed).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you don't need this query at all if you modify your `Filter` model a little bit.

Add has_many through in `Filter` model for `Place`

```
has_many :places, through: :amenities
```

Then call like:

```
@filter = Filter.find(params[:id])
@places = @filter.places
```